# Showing a related fields attribute

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

How would I do this to show the ForeignKey protected_area's name field?:

```
class NotificationReceiverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = NotificationReceiver
        fields = ('pk','cellphone', 'protected_area__name')
```

So now its just showing as PK, as expected:

```
protected_area":1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
class NotificationReceiverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    proteced_area = serializers.ReadOnlyField(source="protected_area.name")

    class Meta:
        model = NotificationReceiver
        fields = ('pk','cellphone', 'protected_area')
```

This will show the protected_area names as a read only field. Alternatively,

```
class NotificationReceiverSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    proteced_area = ProtectedAreaSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = NotificationReceiver
        fields = ('pk','cellphone', 'protected_area')
```

to show all the fields in the related model

Comment: I cant pass serializers.ReadOnlyField() it anything

Comment: protected_area = serializers.ReadOnlyField('protected_area.name')
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Comment: What is your version of DRF? I think we maybe having different versions

Comment: This works! serializers.ReadOnlyField(source='protected_area.name') Just change you answer and I can make it as right answer